# Finding a vertical scrolling arcade game from the 90´s

Tags: identify-this-game, arcade

The game I'm looking for had the possibility for two players controlling a red or blue fighter jet. The style reminds of the "Raiden" games on arcade.

The only specific I remember is that the last stage was in space and the cut sequence before you could see the jets launch horizontal onto a ramp that via a radius turned vertical and off to space they went.

I remember that you could get an upgrade called missiles that left the aircraft slowly backwards before accelerating forward. You could also get homing missiles.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but its not Aero fighters. It looks close though. I remember that you could get an upgrade called missiles that left the aircraft slowly backwards before accelerating forward. You could also get homing missiles.

Comment: Air Assault (Irem, 1993) has red and blue jets

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put any additional info in the question, and *not* in the comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a game from the **Aero Fighters** franchise (also known as **Sonic Wings** in Japan).

Comment: You may want to add images and links to support your theory.